# Run a Python Script for all the files in a directory

Tags: python, loops, directory, nltk, stemming

My programming skills are very(x10) limited.
But I have this little python script:

```
#load data
files = '/Users/xxx/Desktop/Test_SP/a.txt'
file = open(files, 'rt')
text = file.read()
file.close()
# split into words
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
tokens = word_tokenize(text)
# stemming of words
from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer
porter = PorterStemmer()
stemmed = [porter.stem(word) for word in tokens]
print(stemmed[:20])
```

Can someone please tell me how to run this script for **ALL the files in this directory** (`/Users/xxx/Desktop/Test_SP`) and not only for 1 File at a time (`a.txt`)

*(I already know about glob, `os.walk` etc. but I couldn't manage to make it work. Every help is very appreciated.)*

Comment: You want one file at a time, or merge text from all the files and then do tokenize or stemming?

Comment: I want one file at a time. Actually I have second problem -> I get the output with "print(stemmed[:X])" - But I actually want the program to: Open every .txt file in directory -> Do stuff -> Rewrite every .txt file with the new output.

Answer (score 1):

All of your mentioned function should be works to iterating all the files inside the folder. btw, what's your error when try run with those method (`glob`, `os.walk`, etc).
Here is my solution with `listdir`:

```
import os
files_path = '/Users/xxx/Desktop/Test_SP/'
for filename in os.listdir(files_path):
    # only care the txt files
    if filename.endswith(".txt"):
        #load data
        file = open("{}/{}".format(files_path,filename))
        text = file.read()
        file.close()
        # split into words
        from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
        tokens = word_tokenize(text)
        # stemming of words
        from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer
        porter = PorterStemmer()
        stemmed = [porter.stem(word) for word in tokens]
        # write on the same file with input
        with open("{}/{}".format(files_path,filename), 'w') as fout:
            fout.write(stemmed[:20])
```

Comment: Omg thank you so so so so much !!!! It works I can't believe it !!! I was trying to do it for the past days but I have close to zero programming experience (I am very interested in learning though) -> Do you maybe also have a solution for my second question-> I get the output with "print(stemmed[:X])" - But I actually want the program to: Open every .txt file in directory -> Do stuff -> Rewrite every .txt file with the new output.

Comment: Hi @patricks, I edited my answer to re-write the same file with new output. I hopes it works, tell me if you found error, cheers!

Comment: Wow thank you for your effort! I get the following Error right now: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xxx/Desktop/stemmer_small.py", line 19, in <module>
    fout.write(stemmed[:20])
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not list.  (Also maybe I forgot to say this but If I keep "stemmed[:20]" It will only take the first 20 words of each .txt file -> But I need the whole text file

Comment: how about change the write function become writelines, something like `fout.writelines(stemmed)` , writelines will help you to write a list on file, but if it's fail you can just iterate it with for loop to write it.